# Conditional Commands in tox? (tox, travis-ci, and coveralls)

Tags: python, travis-ci, tox, coveralls

*tl;dr:*

I'm setting up CI for a project of mine, hosted on github, using `tox` and `travis-ci`. At the end of the build, I run `converalls` to push the coverage reports to `coveralls.io`. I would like to make this command 'conditional' - for execution only when the tests are run on travis; not when they are run on my local machine. Is there a way to make this happen?

*The details:*

The package I'm trying to test is a python package. I'm using / planning to use the following 'infrastructure' to set up the tests :

- The tests themselves are of the `py.test` variety.
- The CI scripting, so to speak, is from `tox`. This lets me run the tests locally, which is rather important to me. I don't want to have to push to github every time I need a test run. I also use `numpy` and `matplotlib` in my package, so running an inane number of test cycles on `travis-ci` seems overly wasteful to me. As such, ditching `tox` and simply using `.travis.yml` alone is not an option.
- The CI server is `travis-ci`

The relevant test scripts look something like this :

**.travis.yml**

```
language: python
python: 2.7
env:
  - TOX_ENV=py27
install:
  - pip install tox
script:
  - tox -e $TOX_ENV
```

**tox.ini**

```
[tox]
envlist = py27

[testenv]
passenv = TRAVIS TRAVIS_JOB_ID TRAVIS_BRANCH
deps =
    pytest
    coverage
    pytest-cov
    coveralls
commands =
    py.test --cov={envsitepackagesdir}/mypackage --cov-report=term --basetemp={envtmpdir}
    coveralls
```

This file lets me run the tests locally. However, due to the final `coveralls` call, the test fails in principle, with :

```
py27 runtests: commands[1] | coveralls
You have to provide either repo_token in .coveralls.yml, or launch via Travis
ERROR: InvocationError: ...coveralls'
```

This is an expected error. The `passenv` bit sends along the necessary information from `travis` to be able to write to `coveralls`, and without travis there to provide this information, the command should fail. I don't want this to push the results to coveralls.io, either. I'd like to have `coveralls` run only if the test is occuring on `travis-ci`. Is there any way in which I can have this command run conditionally, or set up a build configuration which achieves the same effect?

I've already tried moving the coveralls portion into `.travis.yml`, but when that is executed `coveralls` seems to be unable to locate the appropriate `.coverage` file to send over. I made various attempts in this direction, none of which resulted in a successful submission to `coveralls.io` except the combination listed above. The following was what I would have hoped would work, given that when I run `tox` locally I do end up with a `.coverage` file where I'd expect it - in the root folder of my source tree.

**No submission to coveralls.io**

```
language: python
python: 2.7
env:
  - TOX_ENV=py27
install:
  - pip install tox
  - pip install python-coveralls
script:
  - tox -e $TOX_ENV
after_success:
  - coveralls
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a similar setup with Travis, tox and coveralls. My idea was to only execute `coveralls` if the `TRAVIS` environment variable is set. However, it seems this is not so easy to do as tox has trouble parsing commands with quotes and ampersands. Additionally, this [confused <del>Travis</del> me a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011318/inconsistent-results-with-travis-ci-and-tox).

Eventually I wrote a simple python script `run_coveralls.py`:

```
#!/bin/env/python

import os

from subprocess import call


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if 'TRAVIS' in os.environ:
        rc = call('coveralls')
        raise SystemExit(rc)
```

In `tox.ini`, replace your `coveralls` command with `python {toxinidir}/run_coveralls.py`.

Comment: Nice solution! But it's better to name the script `run_coveralls.py`, to avoid name clash with actual `coveralls` package.

Comment: I wonder how `run_coveralls.py` should most conveniently be included/called? There is an error message `can't open file 'run_coveralls.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` as the file is not copied to the tox' virtual environment. I suppose it should not be included as part of the package.

Comment: I think I managed to find a solution myself. `python {toxinidir}/run_coveralls.py` seems to work.

Comment: You should please remove the `import sys`, because it is not required for your solution...

Comment: See [citeproc-py](https://github.com/brechtm/citeproc-py/tree/4e99750a5ceb26f7a10a1a2f5fb8ef727a9bc16e) for an example `tox.ini` and a more advanced `coveralls.py`.

Answer (score 13):

An alternative solution would be to prefix the `coveralls` command with a dash (`-`) to tell `tox` to ignore its exit code as explained [in the documentation](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#ignoring-a-command-exit-code). This way even failures from `coveralls` will be ignored and `tox` will consider the test execution as successful when executed locally.

Using the example configuration above, it would be as follows:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27

[testenv]
passenv = TRAVIS TRAVIS_JOB_ID TRAVIS_BRANCH
deps =
    pytest
    coverage
    pytest-cov
    coveralls
commands =
    py.test --cov={envsitepackagesdir}/mypackage --cov-report=term --basetemp={envtmpdir}
    - coveralls
```

Comment: Your documentation link is now broken, but man did this save my day.

Answer (score 5):

I am using a environmental variable to run additional commands.

tox.ini

```
commands =
    coverage run runtests.py
    {env:POST_COMMAND:python --version}
```

.travis.yml

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.6"
install: pip install tox-travis
script: tox
env:
  - POST_COMMAND=codecov -e TOX_ENV
```

Now in my local setup, it print the python version. When run from Travis it runs codecov.

Comment: **This is the way.** `{env:POST_COMMAND:python --version}` is the embodiment of brilliance, because it silently reduces to a noop when that environment variable is undefined. *Yes.*

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution if you use a `Makefile` and dont want a new py file:

```
define COVERALL_PYSCRIPT
import os
from subprocess import call

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if 'TRAVIS' in os.environ:
        rc = call('coveralls')
        raise SystemExit(rc)
    print("Not in Travis CI, skipping coveralls")
endef
export COVERALL_PYSCRIPT

coveralls: ## runs coveralls if TRAVIS in env
    @python -c "$$COVERALL_PYSCRIPT"
```

In `tox.ini` add `make coveralls` to `commands`