# Inconsistent results with Travis CI and tox

Tags: python, travis-ci, tox

I have set up continuous integration for my open source project at Travis. [tox](http://tox.testrun.org) seems to be having some problems with quotes in the commands, so I set up a temporary branch for debugging the problem. At this point I am encountering a very strange issue.

The last 3 commits and their build status on Travis:

- [Bla](https://github.com/brechtm/citeproc-py/commit/39701042cfd0cc3a4444ebd923cc6b7aaa7169d5) - build 32 [passed](https://travis-ci.org/brechtm/citeproc-py/builds/84221763)
- [eklzjfljkze](https://github.com/brechtm/citeproc-py/commit/cb1ee866644e52d5520353559e52e777980a5a4c) - build 32 [failed](https://travis-ci.org/brechtm/citeproc-py/builds/84221980)
- [**Revert** "eklzjfljkze"](https://github.com/brechtm/citeproc-py/commit/710166fa33fd1e6313a285e21fc2e9a74f762dae) - build 34 [failed](https://travis-ci.org/brechtm/citeproc-py/builds/84258464)

As the last commit reverts the one that caused the failure, I see no reason why build 34 shouldn't pass. Perhaps Travis is caching some stuff, but Travis's Settings->Caching says "No caches have been created yet". As I'm using the free plan for open source projects, I don't think I can even enable caching.

From previous attempts, I have noticed that if I roll back the branch to the passing commit ('Bla') using `git push --force`, the build will pass again.

All of these commits work fine locally using the same python and tox versions.

What's going on?

**EDIT** Now it's failing in a simular way. Compare builds [36](https://travis-ci.org/brechtm/citeproc-py/builds/84279574) and [37](https://travis-ci.org/brechtm/citeproc-py/builds/84281022). The commit in build 37 only makes a change to the README, so it doesn't affect the build in any way. There must be some kind of conflict with Travis and Tox.

Answer (score 1):

Travis makes a shallow clone, limiting it to the last 50 commits. In my `setup.py` script, I call `git describe` which fails if no tags are present in the clone. Hence, the problem occurs when the shallow clone does not contain any tags...